# Android offline installation

Tags: installation, android-sdk

Is there any other way to download the android sdk platform other than using this URL
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-18_r01.zip.

My ISP has blocked the URL's starting with https://dl.google.com/.

Comment: Download through proxy? Sneakernet?

Comment: Just curious why an ISP would do that. Your profile says you're in India. Are they blocking other Google services also?

Comment: @Chahk: No. In my company they are blocking it.